# Changing file extension

Tags: files, file-format

I have about 1000 images saved in a weird way.

```
"file_name".jpeg?image=%2Fmars%2Freadonly%2Fthemis%2Fpds%2FODTGEO_v2%2Fbrowse%2Fodtbws2_0050%2Fv545xxbws2%2FV54577010POL.png&rotate=0&format=jpeg
```

I want to convert all of the files into just `.jpeg`.

What command do I use?

Comment: You want to remove the part from `?` till the end?

Comment: yeah exactly just have them all as .jpeg

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully follow your quest but I have this little script that can return the filename without that long part but retains the `"` quotes and I suspect that some of those files have spaces in their names so they might have to stay.

```
for i in /path/to/files/*; do mv "$(realpath $i)" "$(realpath "${i%%\?*}"); done
```

Result:

```
"file_name".jpeg
```

**Note:** I couldn't create a sample with that name so I used a varaible in a script.